# How to check if graph contains a negative cycle but it can't be reached from source?

Tags: python-3.x, graph, shortest-path, bellman-ford

I want to check if my weighted graph has a negative cycle. For using bellman-ford algorithm, we need to select a source node, initialize all other distances to infinity and start relaxing n-1 times if number of vertices is n. My problem is that the unreachable nodes will have infinite distance all throughout and won't get changed in nth iteration also. So for an unreachable negative cycle we get wrong output.

```
def negative_cycle(adj, cost):
    dist = [float('inf')] * n
    prev = [None] * n
    dist[0] = 0
    for _ in range(n-1):
        for u, edges in enumerate(adj):
            for i, v in enumerate(edges):
                if dist[v]>dist[u]+cost[u][i]:
                    dist[v]=dist[u]+cost[u][i]
                    prev[v]=u
    for u, edges in enumerate(adj):
        for i, v in enumerate(edges):
            if dist[v]>dist[u]+cost[u][i]:
                return 1
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run it for each connected component. For this, implement your function in the way that it gets a vertex `v` (In your function, it's always vertex `0`), then implement a loop and for each vertex which has distance set to infinity, call your function on that vertex.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the shortest path and simply want to detect a negative cycle, you can set the initial distance of all vertices to 0. This has the same effect as creating an imaginary source *s* and connecting *s* to all other vertices with weight 0 edges.

Your code would then look like the one below (Probably, I don't know Python, so my syntax could be incorrect).

```
def negative_cycle(adj, cost):
    dist = [0] * n
    prev = [None] * n
    for _ in range(n-1):
        for u, edges in enumerate(adj):
            for i, v in enumerate(edges):
                if dist[v]>dist[u]+cost[u][i]:
                    dist[v]=dist[u]+cost[u][i]
                    prev[v]=u
    for u, edges in enumerate(adj):
        for i, v in enumerate(edges):
            if dist[v]>dist[u]+cost[u][i]:
                return 1
    return 0
```